# ethernet bonding in Centos 7 - testing without network connections

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, bonding

I'm configuring a Centos 7 box to do Ethernet bonding of 2 nic's.
I've edited the ifcfg files by hand and said no to NetworkManager.
But it's not coming up.

I'd like to eliminate the config on the network switch, just to isolate the problem, even tho I'm using mode=5 (no switch support needed).

Am I right to think that without any physical network connections, the bond should still come up and show ok in /proc/net/bonding/bond0?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

If all physical slave interfaces are down (no link signal) , then bond interface will be downed automatically.

Before start to edit `ifcfg-eth4` config  file you should down this interface by command `ifdown eth4`. After editing config you can up this interface by command `ifup eth4`.